# Is it possible to use random.number with min and max values in x-faker property for openapi mocking

Tags: mocking, yaml, openapi, faker

I have a yaml file like this:

```
type: object
properties:
  transactionId:
    x-faker: random.uuid
    description: Transaction internal id
    type: string
  description:
    x-faker: lorem.sentence
    description: Transaction description
    type: string
  categoryId:
    x-faker: random.number
    description: Unique id of the category
    type: integer
required:
  - transactionId
  - categoryId
```

I'm [using the prism to mock the API response](https://stoplight.io/p/docs/gh/stoplightio/prism/docs/guides/mock-responses.md) dynamically and it works fine. The only problem is, the `categoryId` is a random number which I don't have any control over it. I want it to be a number between 1 and 10. According to the [faker.js documentation](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/wiki/Random), it is possible to use the `min` and `max` attributes to control the random generator but the `x-faker` property doesn't support using those parameters. I need to use something like this:

```
x-faker: random.number({min:1, max:10})
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across the same issue, looks like doing something like `random.number((1) + 9)` will solve the problem. This would give you a random number between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

As Alison W said, it's best not to use faker for generating generic values like this. Faker produces specific values of a certain shape.

Use a generic library for generating random numbers instead.